# python if wait then statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working on a raspberry pi python script and I am struggling to get the if statement to do what I want.

I can count fingers on a hand in a video stream and this is working fine.

Next I want to initiate a first event (beep) when 5 fingers (defects) are counted, and then proceed into a sub loop where if the 5 fingers subsequently change to zero fingers within a given time (2s) then another second event (click) happens.

This is what I have so far (not quite working):

```
if count_defects==5:
    os.system('mpg321 beep.mp3 -q')
    time.sleep(2)
    if count_defects<5:
        os.system('mpg321 click.mp3 -q')
else:
    cv2.putText(img, "Waiting", (50,50), font, 1, (255,255,255), 1)
```

Hope someone can help
thanks

Comment: You enter your `if` tree when `count_defects == 5`. There is nothing after that point that allows `count_defects` to change value, so `if count_defects < 5` can never be true. I assume this value comes from some kind of function call? If so, you need to call that function again after `time.sleep(2)` to give `count_defects` the opportunity to take a value other than 5.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that count_defects takes an initial value `== 5` to pass the `if` clause. However, it can never then assume another value unless you give it an opportunity to recalculate. I don't know the function you use to get this value, but your code should look something like the following.

```
def check_number_of_fingers():
    return number_of_fingers


count_defects = check_number_of_fingers()

if count_defects == 5:
    os.system('mpg321 beep.mp3 -q')
    time.sleep(2)
    count_defects = check_number_of_fingers() # Recalculate the value after elapsed time
    if count_defects < 5:
        os.system('mpg321 click.mp3 -q')
else:
    cv2.putText(img, "Waiting", (50,50), font, 1, (255,255,255), 1)
```

Comment: Hm.. Can you use a while loop instead of a if clause? `while (count_defects < 5): os.system('mpg321 click.mp3 -q') count_defects = check_number_of_fingers()` and perhaps some sleep in that while loop

Comment: @Ola yes, if you wanted to continually check for an updated value. However, the OP only states that there should be a second event, so a single check

Comment: @Ola well no, I don't think your edited comment does anything like what the OP is asking. Instead of continually checking for an updated number of fingers (which is what I thought you were referring to), your code just constantly plays the mp3 until there are 5 fingers again

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, but the function that counts number of fingers is quite complex.  do I need to define it as check_number_of_fingers()?  I tried your code as is and it said that return number_of_fingers had not been defined.

Comment: @AndreBrown The function that I have written does nothing and will throw an error. It's a placeholder to illustrate how this works, you have to substitute it with your own _real_ function. You can call the function whatever name you like, the point is that you have to rerun the function within the `if` statement, whatever it is called.

Comment: This will always wait 2 seconds, I think its better to use a while loops that stops when  count_defects > 4 or when seconds > 2